# how do I install node, npm, angular cli on MAC?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I've been trying to install the angular cli for several days now with now luck. I've tried installing node manually, and with brew. I've uninstalled node and reinstalled. I've also tried fixing the npm permission with steps found here: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

I've checked that all the appropriate directories have correct permissions. I do think it odd that even when uninstalling and reinstalling the npm config prefix is
'/Users/myusername/.npm-packages' instead of '/usr/local'.

Any help on how to get this installed correctly would be appreciated!

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.
node -v = v8.9.0
npm -v = 5.5.1

When trying to run 'ng version' I get '-bash: ng: command not found'.

**npm config get prefix** =

```
/Users/myusername/.npm-packages
```

**npm config get**

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.5.1 node/v8.9.0 darwin x64"

; userconfig /Users/myusername/.npmrc
prefix = "/Users/myusername/.npm-packages"

; builtin config undefined

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /Users/myusername/.npm-packages/etc
; HOME = /Users/myusername
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

**npm info @angular/cli**

```
{ name: '@angular/cli',
  description: 'CLI tool for Angular',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '1.5.0', next: '1.5.0-rc.8' },
  versions: 
   [ '1.0.0-beta.28.3',
     '1.0.0-beta.29',
     '1.0.0-beta.30',
     '1.0.0-beta.31',
     '1.0.0-beta.32',
     '1.0.0-beta.32.2',
     '1.0.0-beta.32.3',
     '1.0.0-beta.33',
     '1.0.0-beta.33.1',
     '1.0.0-rc.0',
     '1.0.0-rc.1',
     '1.0.0-rc.2',
     '1.0.0-rc.3',
     '1.0.0-rc.4',
     '1.0.0',
     '1.0.1',
     '1.0.2',
     '1.0.3',
     '1.0.4',
     '1.0.5',
     '1.0.6',
     '1.1.0-beta.0',
     '1.1.0-beta.1',
     '1.1.0-rc.0',
     '1.1.0-rc.1',
     '1.1.0-rc.2',
     '1.1.0',
     '1.1.1',
     '1.1.2',
     '1.1.3',
     '1.2.0-beta.0',
     '1.2.0-beta.1',
     '1.2.0-rc.0',
     '1.2.0-rc.1',
     '1.2.0',
     '1.2.1',
     '1.2.2',
     '1.2.3',
     '1.2.4',
     '1.2.5',
     '1.2.6',
     '1.2.7',
     '1.2.8',
     '1.3.0-beta.0',
     '1.3.0-beta.1',
     '1.3.0-rc.0',
     '1.3.0-rc.1',
     '1.3.0-rc.2',
     '1.3.0-rc.3',
     '1.3.0-rc.4',
     '1.3.0-rc.5',
     '1.3.0',
     '1.3.1',
     '1.3.2',
     '1.4.0-beta.0',
     '1.4.0-beta.1',
     '1.4.0-beta.2',
     '1.4.0-rc.0',
     '1.4.0-rc.1',
     '1.4.0-rc.2',
     '1.4.0',
     '1.4.1',
     '1.4.2',
     '1.4.3',
     '1.4.4',
     '1.4.5',
     '1.4.6',
     '1.4.7',
     '1.4.8',
     '1.4.9',
     '1.5.0-beta.0',
     '1.5.0-beta.1',
     '1.5.0-beta.2',
     '1.5.0-beta.3',
     '1.5.0-beta.4',
     '1.5.0-rc.0',
     '1.5.0-rc.1',
     '1.5.0-rc.2',
     '1.5.0-rc.3',
     '1.5.0-rc.4',
     '1.5.0-rc.5',
     '1.5.0-rc.6',
     '1.5.0-rc.7',
     '1.5.0-rc.8',
     '1.5.0' ],
  maintainers: 
   [ 'angular-cli <hansl@google.com>',
     'angular <angular-core+npm@google.com>' ],
  time: 
   { modified: '2017-11-01T19:14:57.082Z',
     created: '2017-02-01T22:39:48.654Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.28.3': '2017-02-01T22:39:48.654Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.29': '2017-02-02T02:31:47.645Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.30': '2017-02-03T01:33:52.259Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.31': '2017-02-09T23:56:06.277Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.32': '2017-02-17T01:51:53.654Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.32.2': '2017-02-17T02:00:52.484Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.32.3': '2017-02-17T02:08:23.149Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.33': '2017-02-25T05:21:36.887Z',
     '1.0.0-beta.33.1': '2017-02-25T05:59:19.475Z',
     '1.0.0-rc.0': '2017-02-25T07:30:35.378Z',
     '1.0.0-rc.1': '2017-03-03T03:12:06.772Z',
     '1.0.0-rc.2': '2017-03-13T23:35:46.979Z',
     '1.0.0-rc.3': '2017-03-21T00:49:12.653Z',
     '1.0.0-rc.4': '2017-03-21T01:33:52.067Z',
     '1.0.0': '2017-03-24T03:08:08.615Z',
     '1.0.1': '2017-04-25T02:55:49.584Z',
     '1.0.2': '2017-05-03T22:57:19.031Z',
     '1.1.0-beta.0': '2017-05-03T23:50:36.374Z',
     '1.0.3': '2017-05-09T21:00:17.413Z',
     '1.1.0-beta.1': '2017-05-09T21:42:35.163Z',
     '1.1.0-rc.0': '2017-05-15T22:19:37.926Z',
     '1.0.4': '2017-05-18T17:54:04.979Z',
     '1.0.5': '2017-05-24T22:17:19.130Z',
     '1.1.0-rc.1': '2017-05-24T22:36:47.469Z',
     '1.0.6': '2017-05-25T17:57:32.914Z',
     '1.1.0-rc.2': '2017-05-25T18:22:24.404Z',
     '1.1.0': '2017-05-31T20:22:53.831Z',
     '1.2.0-beta.0': '2017-05-31T21:13:50.572Z',
     '1.1.1': '2017-06-07T21:01:59.836Z',
     '1.2.0-beta.1': '2017-06-07T21:44:09.173Z',
     '1.1.2': '2017-06-15T20:39:42.222Z',
     '1.2.0-rc.0': '2017-06-15T21:16:57.470Z',
     '1.1.3': '2017-06-21T21:48:12.505Z',
     '1.2.0-rc.1': '2017-06-21T22:31:33.214Z',
     '1.2.0': '2017-06-29T19:21:25.576Z',
     '1.3.0-beta.0': '2017-06-29T19:55:56.904Z',
     '1.2.1': '2017-07-12T17:34:40.198Z',
     '1.3.0-beta.1': '2017-07-12T18:38:33.167Z',
     '1.2.2': '2017-07-20T21:06:26.951Z',
     '1.2.3': '2017-07-21T17:57:50.477Z',
     '1.3.0-rc.0': '2017-07-21T22:22:01.734Z',
     '1.2.4': '2017-07-24T19:01:16.743Z',
     '1.3.0-rc.1': '2017-07-24T19:03:08.281Z',
     '1.2.5': '2017-07-26T21:09:37.299Z',
     '1.3.0-rc.2': '2017-07-26T21:26:55.403Z',
     '1.2.6': '2017-07-27T18:29:09.611Z',
     '1.3.0-rc.3': '2017-07-27T18:55:31.455Z',
     '1.2.7': '2017-08-03T17:51:53.604Z',
     '1.3.0-rc.4': '2017-08-03T18:26:06.546Z',
     '1.3.0-rc.5': '2017-08-03T19:16:35.510Z',
     '1.2.8': '2017-08-09T22:34:57.034Z',
     '1.3.0': '2017-08-09T23:33:40.392Z',
     '1.4.0-beta.0': '2017-08-10T23:31:35.610Z',
     '1.3.1': '2017-08-17T20:44:40.289Z',
     '1.4.0-beta.1': '2017-08-18T00:00:02.218Z',
     '1.4.0-beta.2': '2017-08-18T19:06:12.921Z',
     '1.3.2': '2017-08-23T22:03:53.021Z',
     '1.4.0-rc.0': '2017-08-23T22:11:28.919Z',
     '1.4.0-rc.1': '2017-08-25T21:05:15.145Z',
     '1.4.0-rc.2': '2017-08-30T00:23:14.662Z',
     '1.4.0': '2017-09-07T16:31:09.637Z',
     '1.4.1': '2017-09-08T22:39:19.578Z',
     '1.5.0-beta.0': '2017-09-14T00:03:25.612Z',
     '1.4.2': '2017-09-14T00:35:39.637Z',
     '1.4.3': '2017-09-22T02:00:04.404Z',
     '1.5.0-beta.1': '2017-09-22T02:02:52.519Z',
     '1.4.4': '2017-09-28T23:01:05.205Z',
     '1.5.0-beta.2': '2017-09-28T23:03:16.645Z',
     '1.5.0-beta.3': '2017-10-03T20:33:31.803Z',
     '1.4.5': '2017-10-05T21:29:06.347Z',
     '1.5.0-beta.4': '2017-10-05T21:32:26.527Z',
     '1.4.6': '2017-10-12T01:31:14.231Z',
     '1.4.7': '2017-10-12T16:52:14.901Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.0': '2017-10-12T17:28:05.424Z',
     '1.4.8': '2017-10-18T20:09:29.000Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.1': '2017-10-18T20:13:37.270Z',
     '1.4.9': '2017-10-19T22:54:59.961Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.2': '2017-10-19T23:36:26.426Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.3': '2017-10-24T05:17:28.861Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.4': '2017-10-26T17:21:40.607Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.5': '2017-10-27T01:21:13.361Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.6': '2017-10-28T00:35:11.786Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.7': '2017-10-30T18:27:09.785Z',
     '1.5.0-rc.8': '2017-10-30T23:39:34.512Z',
     '1.5.0': '2017-11-01T19:14:57.082Z' },
  homepage: 'https://github.com/angular/angular-cli',
  keywords: [ 'angular', 'angular-cli', 'Angular CLI' ],
  repository: 
   { type: 'git',
     url: 'git+https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.git' },
  author: 'Angular Authors',
  bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues' },
  license: 'MIT',
  readmeFilename: 'README.md',
  users: 
   { avil13: true,
     tonimoeckel: true,
     jota: true,
     baschte: true,
     stormos: true,
     szamocza: true,
     db6edr: true,
     willvanpelt: true,
     'ognjen.jevremovic': true,
     plastikaweb: true,
     waiwaiku: true,
     adli: true,
     reekdeb: true,
     'n.sanitate': true,
     niilante: true,
     qingqingcao: true,
     stefaans: true,
     'jlouros-io': true,
     fadihania: true,
     wilda: true,
     fdagosti: true,
     albertico88: true,
     kremr: true,
     plauret: true,
     infrabill: true,
     manojkhannakm: true,
     julianomontini: true,
     'stone-jin': true,
     springy: true,
     fmakareev: true,
     rastrearcelularonline: true,
     majkel: true,
     onsentamago: true,
     markymark: true,
     korbraan: true,
     allen_l_liu: true,
     polyeezy: true,
     joshdoescode: true,
     sirhcybe: true,
     shadster: true,
     samersm: true,
     tommyldunn: true,
     willwm: true,
     aran_sk: true,
     khcjump: true,
     orenschwartz: true,
     yangzw: true,
     stephanlv: true,
     advpat: true,
     tifbs: true,
     johnnyjohnjohn: true,
     iamclaytonray: true,
     shekharreddy: true,
     elijahsh: true },
  version: '1.5.0',
  main: 'lib/cli/index.js',
  trackingCode: 'UA-8594346-19',
  bin: { ng: './bin/ng' },
  engines: { node: '>= 6.9.0', npm: '>= 3.0.0' },
  dependencies: 
   { '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer': '~0.0.31',
     '@angular-devkit/schematics': '~0.0.34',
     '@ngtools/json-schema': '1.1.0',
     '@ngtools/webpack': '1.8.0',
     '@schematics/angular': '~0.1.0',
     autoprefixer: '^6.5.3',
     chalk: '~2.2.0',
     'circular-dependency-plugin': '^3.0.0',
     'common-tags': '^1.3.1',
     'copy-webpack-plugin': '^4.1.1',
     'core-object': '^3.1.0',
     'css-loader': '^0.28.1',
     cssnano: '^3.10.0',
     denodeify: '^1.2.1',
     'ember-cli-string-utils': '^1.0.0',
     'exports-loader': '^0.6.3',
     'extract-text-webpack-plugin': '3.0.0',
     'file-loader': '^1.1.5',
     'fs-extra': '^4.0.0',
     glob: '^7.0.3',
     'html-webpack-plugin': '^2.29.0',
     'karma-source-map-support': '^1.2.0',
     less: '^2.7.2',
     'less-loader': '^4.0.5',
     'license-webpack-plugin': '^1.0.0',
     lodash: '^4.11.1',
     'memory-fs': '^0.4.1',
     'node-modules-path': '^1.0.0',
     nopt: '^4.0.1',
     opn: '~5.1.0',
     portfinder: '~1.0.12',
     'postcss-custom-properties': '^6.1.0',
     'postcss-loader': '^1.3.3',
     'postcss-url': '^5.1.2',
     'raw-loader': '^0.5.1',
     resolve: '^1.1.7',
     rxjs: '^5.5.2',
     'sass-loader': '^6.0.3',
     semver: '^5.1.0',
     'silent-error': '^1.0.0',
     'source-map-loader': '^0.2.0',
     'source-map-support': '^0.4.1',
     'istanbul-instrumenter-loader': '^2.0.0',
     'style-loader': '^0.13.1',
     stylus: '^0.54.5',
     'stylus-loader': '^3.0.1',
     'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin': '1.0.0',
     'url-loader': '^0.6.2',
     webpack: '~3.8.1',
     'webpack-concat-plugin': '1.4.0',
     'webpack-dev-middleware': '~1.12.0',
     'webpack-dev-server': '~2.9.3',
     'webpack-merge': '^4.1.0',
     'webpack-sources': '^1.0.0',
     'webpack-subresource-integrity': '^1.0.1',
     'zone.js': '^0.8.14',
     'node-sass': '^4.3.0' },
  optionalDependencies: { 'node-sass': '^4.3.0' },
  dist: 
   { integrity: 'sha512-nCXvqNCdi+8aOU2v6EABZsMg5bB7iM+wfaoWKnu9M5fOW2Rm+7/3Y1gDQKyFkgXCzXdy3J/xpfmwT0gjmjlvIA==',
     shasum: '2abc3ff1648d54ad4a14f82f9d517f371370406c',
     tarball: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/cli/-/cli-1.5.0.tgz' },
  directories: {} }
```

Comment: do you like to remove the complete node and reinstall it? If that's can be done I will help you to get set from scratch

Comment: yes. i'll do a complete uninstall again

Comment: i hope my answer solves your problem then?

Answer (score 1):

I'll be talking about **Angular CLI** only.

With reference to [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), I'll assume that you tried installing it without `-g` flag with NPM.

**Step 1: Install Angular CLI from NPM**

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

**Step 2: Generate a new app from Angular CLI**

`ng new <APP NAME>`

**Step 3: Changing directories**

`cd <APP NAME>`

**Step 4: Serving your app**

`ng serve`

If all fails, please have a try of the following.

**Step 1: Changing directories (Fallback Option)**

`cd <NPM ANGULAR CLI DIRECTORY>`

**Step 2: Running `ng` locally (Fallback Option)**

`./bin/ng new <APP NAME> --directory <WHERE EVER YOU WANT IT TO GENERATE>`

Hope this helps.